# Count by ID in Lambda Expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, count, group-by

I have Meetings and Cities tables and joined both of them with lambda expression. On the other hand I set a property "Expired" according to the meeting date as below. Instead of the Expired property below, I want to use Total property so that checking the total count of each applicant for a meeting **with the same MeetingID**. Wşth the help of this, I can  determine if there are 50 person for the same meeting (by the same meeting ID) in Meetings table and prevent users to apply more than 50 person.

In my code below I use Expired parameter that is set according to the MeetingDate property. I need to assign such a kind of property like "Full" in order to get a total applicant for each meeting by id. How can I do this in Lambda expression below?

**City Model:**

```
public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

**Meeting Model:**

```
public class Meeting
{
    public int MeetingID { get; set; }
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    public DateTime MeetingStartDate { get; set; }       
    public DateTime? MeetingEndDate { get; set; }
    public int? TotalParticipant { get; set; }
    public int? MeetingCityId { get; set; }
}
```

**Applicant Model:**

```
public class Applicant
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicantID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmitDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }   
    public int MeetingId { get; set; } 
}
```

**Controller:**

```
var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
            .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
                (m, c) => new
                {
                    CityID = c.CityID,
                    CityName = c.CityName,
                    MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate
                }
            )
            .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(
                i => new
                {
                    Value = i.CityID.ToString(),
                    DisplayValue = string.Format(
                        "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
                        i.CityName, i.MeetingDate),
                    Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                    Full = ... ???
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Let me guess what *total applicant* means...

Comment: Its not really clear what you want `Full` to be.. What do you mean by "total applicant for each meeting"?

Comment: I explained with detail on the first paragraph. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if your meetings have relations with applicants, then:

```
        var meetingsQuery = repository.Meetings
        .Join(repository.Cities, m => m.MeetingCityId, c => c.CityID,
            (m, c) => new
            {
                CityID = c.CityID,
                CityName = c.CityName,
                MeetingDate = m.MeetingStartDate,
                ApplicantsCount = m.Applicants.Count(),

            }
        )
        .OrderBy(x => x.CityID)
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(
            i => new
            {
                Value = i.CityID.ToString(),
                DisplayValue = string.Format(
                    "{0} ({1:dd MMMM yyyy})",
                    i.CityName, i.MeetingDate),
                Expired = i.MeetingDate < DateTime.UtcNow,
                Full = i.ApplicantsCount >= MaxApplicantsCount
            }
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But there is no Count method for neither "Applicants" nor "MeetingId" on ApplicantsCount = m.Applicants.Count() line. Any idea to correct it?

Comment: i cant be more helpful without knowing your model

Comment: do you have participants table? Or how are applicants related to meeting?

Comment: Yes, I added Applicant model also and it is related to Meetings model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Voted+